# Maintaining Maximum Social Distance

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I wrote this simple program to place a certain number of people on a list of `seats` whilst maintaining maximum social distance.

Given that there is at least one empty seat, calculate the maximum.distance from an empty seat to the closest occupied seat and return the available seat.
How can this be improved to be better

```
// seats.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr int N = 50;

int traverse_right(const std::array<int, N> &seats, int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        return 0;
    else if(seats[i] == 1)
        return i;
    else return traverse_right(seats, --i);
}

int traverse_left(const std::array<int, N> &seats, int i)
{
    if (i >= seats.size())
        return 0;
    else if(seats[i] == 1)
        return i;
    else return traverse_left(seats, ++i);
}

int get_available_seat(const std::array<int, N> &seats)
{
    int max = 0;
    int right_distance = 0;
    int left_distance = 0;
    int available_seat = -1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i != seats.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(seats[i] == 0)
        {
            right_distance = abs(i - traverse_right(seats, i));
            left_distance = abs(i - traverse_left(seats, i));
        }
        if(left_distance > max && right_distance > max)
        {
            if(left_distance <= right_distance && left_distance != 0)
                max = left_distance;
            else 
                max = right_distance;
            available_seat = i;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Maximum distance to available_seat is " << max << '\n';
    return available_seat;
}

void display(const std::array<int, N> &seats)
{
    for(const auto x : seats)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    std::array<int, N> seats{};
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        int available_seat  = get_available_seat(seats);
        seats[available_seat] = 1;
    }
    display(seats);
}
```

The code works as expected and though I didn't perform the check, user would need to test if there is an available seat before placing.

Comment: Please define "maximum social distance". Is this the *largest distance between the closest people*? *largest average distance from each person to the next closest person*? Or something else? (Your code does not find either of these things)

Comment: @trentcl I have edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Be careful with signed and unsigned

The code compares an `int` `i` with `seats.size()`.  However, `seats.size()` is unsigned and `i` is signed.  For consistency, it would be better to declare `i` as `std::size_t` which is the type returned by `size()`.

### Use standard library functions

The `display` function isn't bad, but it is probably not really needed, either.  Instead of `display(seats)`, I'd write this:

```
std::copy(seats.begin(), seats.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

### Rethink the algorithm

There are problems with the current algorithm.  It produces this result:

```
...X..X..X..X..X..X..X..X.....X.....X.....X......X
```

It's not hard to notice that people on the left are closer together than they need to be and people are the right have extra room.  Hint: there is a simple mathematical way to figure out how many spaces should be between occupied seats.

### Clearly state the goal

Are the chairs in a circle?  If so, your one-chair-at-a-time algorithm works.  If not, there's a missed opportunity: after the first person sits at one end, the maximum distance is achieved if the second person sits at the other end, and not in the middle.  However, assuming it's a circle, it doesn't matter which chair is chosen first.  Here's how I would approach that, using a single non-recursive function using standard library functions:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator find_seat(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end) {
    auto left_empty{begin};
    auto right_occupied{begin};
    auto dist{right_occupied - left_empty};
    for (auto b{begin}; b != end; ++begin) {
        // find the first unoccupied chair (marker a)
        begin = std::find(begin, end, 0);
        // now find first occupied chair to the right, or end (marker b)
        b = std::find(begin, end, 1);
        // if (b-a) > dist, dist=b-a, left=a, right=b
        if ((b - begin) > dist) {
            dist = b - begin;
            left_empty = begin;
            right_occupied = b;
        }
    } 
    // return left_empty + dist/2
    return left_empty + dist/2;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, N> seats{};
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        int available_seat  = get_available_seat(seats);
        seats[available_seat] = 1;
    }
    std::copy(seats.begin(), seats.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Note that in this version, only a single forward pass is made through the container and that, by using a template, we are free to use any kind of container, including `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc.  It's up to the caller to assure that there is at least one empty chair.

Comment: I guess it depends on the intent of the algorithm. If it attempts to figure out how a group of people would greedily fill a row of seats one by one, then it works as expected. If it actually attempts to maximize the distance between people, then you're right the greedy approach is suboptimal.

Comment: The intent is to maximize the distance and make sure the individual is as far as possible from the next individual, both on the left and right.

Comment: @Edward If I get your algorithm well it moves only in one direction. This should mean, it assumes at least one non empty chair?

Comment: Not quite. The algorithm is simple: find the longest empty span and return an iteration that points to the middle of that span.

Answer (score 3):

One idea would be to maintain a distance to the nearest seat, rather than simply an occupancy list (you can recover the same information since seats with zero distance are occupied). Then finding the seat with the furthest distance and updating the list reduces to:

1. finding the maximum element in the array
2. Traversing left and right from that element and updating the distances until the stored distance is already less than the distance to the newly added seat.

One more code review comment:
It may be nicer to either (1) template these functions on the parameter N, rather than declaring it at the beginning, so that they can be called later on a different sized array or (2) use std::vector so that the size of the seats container doesn't need to be known at compile time.

Comment: Good ideas.  Also, if you used a `std::vector` and read from `stdin` or a file, you could tackle the more interesting question, "If you walk into a room with a row of chairs, choose a seat that maximizes your distance to others."  Even better: make it 2D or 3D or more dimensions.

Comment: I find it a little hard to grasp your algorithm.

Comment: Here's an example to maybe clear it up.

Suppose you have an arbitrary row of 20 seats with 6 people in it. The occupancy map might look like [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]. The corresponding maximum distance map would look like [2,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,1,0,1].
To find the seat that is furthest from anyone you just need to find the max of this array, which is the element at position 12 that contains the value 12.

To insert someone at position 12, set 12 to zero, then march backwards and set element 11 to 1 and element 10 to 2, then do the same marching forwards